# How do I set GLIBCXX_FORCE_NEW=1 in cmake for DEBUG builds only?

Tags: gcc, cmake

I need to set the environment variable GLIBCXX_FORCE_NEW=1 for DEBUG builds only, in cmake.

In the cmake documentation, I could only find:

- CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER
- CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS
- CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG
- CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE
- CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The environment variable `GLIBCXX_FORCE_NEW` only affects the behavior of a compiled program at runtime (see the [gcc documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/debug.html)). Adding it as a preprocessor define during compile time of a program (e.g., by setting the CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS) will not have an effect.

With CMake you can set an environment variable that affects the runtime of a built target only for [CMake tests](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-properties.7.html#properties-on-tests). The following commands add a test valid for DEBUG builds, which will run an executable with the `GLIBCXX_FORCE_NEW` variable set:

```
add_test(NAME MyTest CONFIGURATIONS Debug COMMAND MyExecutable)
set_tests_properties(MyTest PROPERTIES ENVIRONMENT "GLIBCXX_FORCE_NEW=1")
```

Answer (score 2):

You want `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE`.

You can check for build type using `if(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE STREQUAL "Debug")`.

Also, be aware that STREQUAL is case-sensitive, so you might want to `string(UPPERCASE ...)` your variable before check.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need an "environment variable" for builds? If you want to set compiler or preprocessor flag for debug builds only , use CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG, e.g

`SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG} -DGLIBCXX_FORCE_NEW=1")`

Don't test `if(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE STREQUAL "Debug")`,  it won't work on all non-Makefile CMake generators (OSX with Xcode, Windows with Visual Studio)

Comment: because it is what gcc wants (I need to set this so valgrind is happy):  http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/bk01pt04ch11.html `To globally disable memory caching within the library for the default allocator, merely set GLIBCXX_FORCE_NEW (with any value) in the system's environment before running the program. If your program crashes with GLIBCXX_FORCE_NEW in the environment, it likely means that you linked against objects built against the older library (objects which might still using the cached allocations...).`

Comment: It is about runtime then, rather than compilation. Thus sakra's answer would be correct one.

Comment: For preprocessor directives in general, a space is needed after `-D`, i.e.: `SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG} -D GLIBCXX_FORCE_NEW=1")`