# GLIBCXX_FORCE_NEW=1 causing binary failure with std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string error

Tags: c++, c++11, abi

I am using a binary which is linked to the object built against the older libraries which are still using the cached allocations. As the GLIBCXX_FORCE_NEW is set in the running environment the binary is failing with below error.

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007f80a3f39495 in raise () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007f80a3f3ac75 in abort () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#2  0x00007f80a528a0d5 in __gnu_cxx::__verbose_terminate_handler() () 
from /opt/lib/libstdc++.so.6
#3  0x00007f80a5288166 in ?? () from /opt/lib/libstdc++.so.6
#4  0x00007f80a5288193 in std::terminate() () from 
/opt/lib/libstdc++.so.6
#5  0x00007f80a52883e6 in __cxa_throw () from /opt/lib/libstdc++.so.6
#6  0x00007f80a52e3262 in std::__throw_logic_error(char const*) () from 
/opt/lib/libstdc++.so.6
#7  0x00007f80a52ef6f1 in char* std::string::_S_construct<char const*>
(char const*, char const*, std::allocator<char> const&, 
std::forward_iterator_tag) ()
from /opt/lib/libstdc++.so.6
#8  0x00007f80a52efac8 in std::basic_string<char, 
std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(char 
const*, std::allocator<char> const&) ()
from /opt/lib/libstdc++.so.6
```

How can I come over this problem without changing the older libraries. Setting the  GLIBCXX_FORCE_NEW=0 is not helping at all.

Thanks.

Comment: If "[s]etting the GLIBCXX_FORCE_NEW=0 is not helping at all", how do you know "GLIBCXX_FORCE_NEW=1 [is] causing" the problem?

Comment: I am also not quite sure about this. But the discussion in the below thread made me think this.  I am in the similar situation as one of the comment is describing.                                    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8464483/how-do-i-set-glibcxx-force-new-1-in-cmake-for-debug-builds-only

Comment: @T.C. that would be a bug, where `if GLIBCXX_FORCE_NEW` is used instead of `ifdef GLIBCXX_FORCE_NEW` (the doc says the macro can be set to anything)